# Understanding and Clarification on AIX and Batch File

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, aix

I am new to AIX and I have trouble understanding the codes stated in the shell script as shown below, I have a few questions.

```
if [ "$OutChlName" != "" ] ; then 
   echo START CHANNEL \($OutChlName\)
fi
```

1. For the first line, what does the `""` mean, does it mean null?
2. `\($OutChlName\)` - is there any way to convert this to a batch file format.
3. Is it right to say that `fi` is the end tag of `if`?

Thank you.

Comment: The tags linux/aix and windows/batch-file are IMO contrdictory. The ?bash? code means if the var is not empty echo...

Answer (score 0):

1. The echo is only wanted when the variable `OutChkName` is filled.
   The string is compared with an empty string.
   When you read `man test`, you can find the alternative `if [ -n "$OutChlName" ]`.
2. echo with double quotes
   Within quotes you do not need the backslashes.

   `echo "START CHANNEL ($OutChlName)"`
   My `echo` behaves different when the OutChlName variable has special characters like newlines or `*`. I think my syntax is a slight bugfix, but when you do not want to change the original behaviour, you can use
   `echo "START CHANNEL ("$OutChlName")"`
   Using backslashes is also a valid syntax (batch format).

   3. `fi` ends `if`
      Also `esac` ends `case`, and `done` ends `do` (Odd, it should have been `od`).